# Storage in computers?

Tags: binary

If i want to save something in a computer such as a number 1 that would be 001 but if i save 001 in a computer how would the computer know that 001 is 1. Should we first save  the number 1 in memory and tell the computer that hey this is 1 and it is 001 in your language. Basically if we want to save something, how would a computer know what are we saving to determine its output. Like if i say the computer hey i wanna save 10011 and i actually intended it to be The letter A how would the computer know 10011 is A?

Comment: It looks like you need to learn [what is plaintext data and what is binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434885).

Comment: The computer doesn't know anything. It just follows orders.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, all computers are built following certain conventions. One of those conventions is the use of zero and one (i.e. low voltage and high voltage): it's perfectly possible to make computers that *don't* use zeroes and ones, and in fact the Soviets did so (look into the Setun project). Another of those conventions is that text-based data comes in units of eight bits each, called "bytes".

Each byte holds a number from zero to 255, and more conventions define what each number means. The ASCII standard, for example, says that 65 means "A", while the UTF-8 standard says that 195 followed by 184 means "ø". But there's nothing intrinsically "A"-like about the number 65: it's just a convention people have agreed to follow, to make it easier for programs to work together.

(P.S. When two programs are using different conventions, you get a garbled mess called "[mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)". Nowadays most text data is stored in UTF-8, which helps avoid this, but there are still some holdouts (*cough* Windows API) who insist on using other conventions instead. It's a headache when you have to deal with that.)